# Replace or show another image o top of a img tag on hover

Tags: css, css-selectors

I've checked other questions but they don't apply to my case and I'm not sure if it's even possible.

I need to replace the image when I hover it.

I cannot use javascript or change the html. I can only  use CSS.

I've tried many many ways I even managed to do it, by using visibility: hidden; on the img and applying a background image on the parent.

However, it became useless, since the img tag is where the action is.

HTML

```
 <ul class="or-body-icons ZERO">
    <li id="liIconDest-or1">
       <img id="iconDest-or1" tabindex="-1" alt="Negócios" src="https://img2.gratispng.com/20180320/bke/kisspng-computer-icons-clip-art-sales-ico-5ab10c441b8ca8.6504430515215524521129.jpg" title="Negócios" style="cursor: pointer" width="16" height="16" border="0">
    </li>
 </ul>
```

CSS

```
.ZERO {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
border: 0;
}

#iconDest-or1{
 width:150px;
 height:100px;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
}


#liIconDest-or1:hover {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 background-image: url(https://img2.gratispng.com/20180304/rde/kisspng-ico-pencil-icon-pencil-5a9c43a0652ef3.9860290115201903684145.jpg);
 background-size: 320px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 cursor: pointer;
 z-index: 10;
 position: relative;
 width:320px;
 height:320px;
 }

ul.or-body-icons li {
list-style-type: none;
float: left;
width: auto;
height: 16px;
line-height: 16px;
margin: 3px 2px;
padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add some CSS to the li element to hide any images inside it when the li is hovered. That will fix your issue applying “visibility: hidden” to the img on hover:

```
#liIconDest-or1:hover img {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: @BrunoDeFaria Instead of “visibility: hidden”, you could try “display: none” or “opacity: 0”

Answer (score 0):

You can change the background image using the hover pseudo-selector:

https://jsfiddle.net/moy2010/sgu2jft4/3/

```
#test {
  background-image: url('https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff');
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

#test:hover {
  background-image: url('https://dummyimage.com/600x300/000/fff');
}
```

Edit:

Didn't notice you wanted to override the image coming from the img tag. Here's an updated jsfiddle for it:

https://jsfiddle.net/moy2010/sgu2jft4/8/

Comment: I've try already before with visibility: hidden, but I cannot use it. There are javascripts acting there. But thanks for the effort.